# doctrine2 nested join query builder

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following working MySQL query:

```
select * from (categories as C
  JOIN category_details as CD ON C.current_category_detail_id = CD.id
  LEFT JOIN (categorized_items as CI 
             JOIN item_details as ID ON CI.item_detail_id = ID.id
             JOIN items as I ON I.current_item_detail_id = ID.id)
  ON CD.id = CI.category_detail_id)                                      
WHERE (CI.current = 1 OR CI.id is NULL)
```

Now I need this in Doctrine2 DQL or QueryBuilder.
I already set the OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations for all my entities, but I need something to make a nested join working.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get an error message?

Comment: @lxg I don't know how to make 2 joins with query builder then make leftJoin between the result and another table on some condition like the query above